# Timeseries in Kibana

Tags: kibana

i've a timeseries in elasticsearch

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-04-11T12:53:16.000Z,
      "@version" => "1",
           "idx" => "915",
          "type" => "testrecord",
     "timestamp" => "1491915196"
}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-04-11T12:53:16.000Z,
      "@version" => "1",
           "idx" => "715",
          "type" => "testrecord",
     "timestamp" => "1491915196"
}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-04-11T12:53:16.000Z,
      "@version" => "1",
           "idx" => "609",
          "type" => "testrecord",
     "timestamp" => "1491915196"
}
```

what i want to do is to show the absolut values in kibana as a timeline means on the x-axis the timestamp on the y-axis the value of idx.

i've searched and tried but except aggregations and counts i didn't find any solution to this quite simple approach in kibana!

Comment: That's a historgram in kibana

Comment: you mean linechart > type histogramm for x-axis? but on the y-axis i've only count, average, sum etc. ... or am i completly wrong?

Comment: Yes x-axis aggregate by Date Histogram, the Y-axis is a bit trickier, normally I just aggregate by count as I just want to see how many messages were received in a given time period. That is generally what kibana is designed for. What happens if you use median for your Y-axis? Assuming you have your results spread out enough on the histogram they shouldn't affect each other, and you should just see the point for idx in each time frame.

Comment: good point, although i have a very high frequency of testdata and therefore i think i have to build something different for such a case. just a simple timestamp-value curve ...!!! thanks for your suggestion and help!